# Ports in the TimeCapsule

Tags: time-capsule

In a few days I'm going to buy my first Mac (an iMac) as well as a Time Capsule. Looking at the specs of that product, I've seen that it has a WAN port and 3 Ethernet Ports. 
I suppose that the WAN port is to connect the TimeCapsule with the Internet. At home, I get Internet trough a Ethernet wire (it's not an ADSL connection). 
My question is: will I be able to connect the Ethernet wire into the WAN port in order to share my Internet connection wirelessly over the house? 

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the port you'll use. If you use one of the other ports, Internet access will sometimes work but the device will think it won't.

Use the WAN port for your apartment's inbound Internet (whether an Ethernet cable or from an ADSL or cable modem), and the other three ports for outbound to your local machines that aren't on wireless.

Comment: As you say, the Ethernet wire plugged in the WAN Port will work ok. I hope that! Thank you so much!